# problems triggering a build in Jenkins with bitbucket-plugin

Tags: networking, jenkins

I installed Jenkins using [Turnkey-Linux Jenkins-VM](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/jenkins), running in a virtual server environment (Windows host in Virtualbox) with a local private IP address and operating on port 80. The development team and I are all remote, so we need to have Jenkins exposed over Internet. The private network in Virtualbox is set to bridged, as per Turnkey-Linux install instructions. The router at this location is using NAT to translate incoming requests on port 8181 on the WAN interface to the Jenkins local IP on port 80, only for certain incoming IPs.

Under this setup, I am able to log into Jenkins from the outside, update Jenkins, set up jobs that grab code from our SCM hosted on Bitbucket, build it, send out emails, everything looks great!

I would really like to have the build jobs triggered by the [bitbucket-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin). I installed it on Jenkins, configured it for my job, set up Bitbucket to POST to $CORPORATE_WEB:8181/bitbucket-hook, and we allowed the Bitbucket IPs to go through the firewall. We have run packet captures on the router and have seen requests from the Bitbucket IP address hitting the WAN interface of the router on port 8181 and being forwarded to the Jenkins box. Unfortunately nothing happens in Jenkins: No build is triggered, and the Bitbucket trigger log is empty!

I tried manually going to $CORPORATE_WEB:8181/bitbucket-hook and get [this issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-23681), which in my case is a good thing? We also tried completely opening up the firewall and triggering a git push, still nothing in Jenkins.

What else can I try to figure out where is the problem?

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Comment: Like I said: at the firewall the POST was received and passed on. Jenkins has nothing. I am not sure where else to look.

Comment: Everything up to your server looks fine, so this is more of a Jenkins/plugin issue rather than your server itself being misconfigured. That makes this pretty much [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Oldskool That sucks. I suspected as much; actually both: the server setup, and unfortunately the off-topic. Still nice to have someone else confirm that I am right ... even when I am wrong. :(

Comment: Jenkins should run on servers. So, asking help to setup Jenkins is off-topic, but for Apache 2.2 is on-topic. Double standard? The bitbucket trigger was always hard to get right. Most of the time, Jenkins permissions are blocking anonymous calls.